# Why static final variables are accepted in local classes?

Tags: java, class, static, local, final

I've googled this extensively to no avail. I cannot seem to wrap my head around this concept. Why are static final fields accepted in local classes? Such as the following example below:

```
public void sayGoodbyeInEnglish() {

        class EnglishGoodbye {
            public static final String farewell = "Bye bye";
            public void sayGoodbye() {
                System.out.println(farewell);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(EnglishGoodbye.farewell);
        EnglishGoodbye myEnglishGoodbye = new EnglishGoodbye();
        myEnglishGoodbye.sayGoodbye();
    }
```

In class EnglishGoodbye the variable farewell is allowed? Why? I'm confused. Why is that allowed but no static variable? I understand why it cannot access the members of the enclosing scope unless they are a compiler time constant as those variables cease to exist when the function ends but the class may not. Right? Im just confused on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not, in general.

But `farewell` is a special kind of static final: one whose value is a constant, as defined by [JLS 15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28). That means that it's not being initialized at that location, which is what's actually disallowed in non-static classes (including local classes), as per [JLS 8.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3).

The JLS states this explicitly (and in bold font) in 8.1.3 (note the "unless" part):

> **It is a compile-time error if an inner class declares a member that is explicitly or implicitly static, unless the member is a constant variable (§4.12.4).**

If you change that line to either remove the `final` modifier or make the expression non-constant (for example, `new String("Bye bye")`), then you'll get the compilation error you expect:

```
Test.java:5: error: Illegal static declaration in inner class EnglishGoodbye
            public static final String farewell = new String("Bye bye");
                                       ^
  modifier 'static' is only allowed in constant variable declarations
1 error
```

---

A bit more:

The reason this is allowed is that constant variables are treated specially by the compiler. In particular, it's allowed to inline them -- the resulting bytecode doesn't have the `farewell` field at all! If you decompile the class (`javap -c YourClassName`), you'll see something like this:

```
public void sayGoodbyeInEnglish();
  Code:
     0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
     3: ldc           #3                  // String Bye bye
     5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
     ...
```

The above corresponds to this line:

```
System.out.println(EnglishGoodbye.farewell);
```

It's a bit daunting, but notice that "3:" line. The program isn't loading the value of the field `farewell`, it's loading constant #3 (which it note in a comment is the String "Bye bye") (you can see a list of the bytecodes [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_bytecode_instruction_listings)).

Because `farewell` is a constant variable (and not a "real" static member), and thus can be inlined in the code, it doesn't matter where you define it -- the variable's lifecycle is essentially that of the whole JVM, not any one class or instance, and thus it can be declared anywhere.

Comment: So wait. Its not initialized at that location? What?